# How to stop a laravel SyncQueue

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I've tried queue:clear, even tried removing all jobs but when I add them again the former queue starts working again as evidenced by the timely log entries, I'd just like to start fresh but couldn't find any way to actually stop the former queue

Comment: What is your error? What do you mean with "the former queue starts working again"? What do you mean with "I would like to start fresh"? Fresh what? You need to add more information as it is absolutely not understandable

Comment: i do not understand why it would not be understandable, start fresh as in start without a queue running, queue:clear doesnt didn't work on SyncQueue as it returns "Clearing queues is not supported on [SyncQueue]", the former queue is the one im trying to stop, as is written on the question

Comment: Start fresh means nothing, but specially "start not running a queue", start fresh would mean `queue:clear`... And Sync is a queue that instantly runs, it is not an asynchronous queue, so you can't stop it, just don't use that queue... Read the docs please. Sync will not wait for an available worker, it will literally run as code from that request

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

This will stop all running queue workers so that you can start fresh with a new worker process.

Comment: this does not seem to work unfortunately since the laravel.log still seems to be getting updated with current time stamps from the job